# how to select rows within groups based on dynamic dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe: each participant has multiple rows and different start times. I want to select all rows within the first minute for each participant. Because each participant started at a different time, the start and end dates must be dynamic.

| id | participant | start_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44414 | 1556 | 2023-04-18 09:35:41.100 |
| 36905 | 1435 | 2023-04-18 09:35:41.300 |
| 44416 | 1556 | 2023-04-18 09:35:42.100 |
| 44417 | 1556 | 2023-04-18 09:35:42.900 |
| 44418 | 1222 | 2023-04-18 09:35:43.100 |
| 44356 | 1899 | 2023-04-18 23:01:29.400 |

So far, I sorted the data based on start_time, grouped it based on participant id, and later used apply to specify the data range I want my selection to follow.

```
df['start_time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])

x = df.sort_values('start_time',ascending=True).groupby(['participant']).apply(lambda g: pd.date_range(start=df['start_time'].min(), end = df['start_time'].max(), periods=len(g),freq='60S').to_series()).values
```

The expected result will be: for each participant, only show rows within the first minute and exclude the rest of the entries. But, I receive the following error:

> **ValueError**: Of the four parameters: start, end, periods, and freq,
> exactly three must be specified

How can I achieve my goal? And is there a better way to perform my target selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with a custom function and return a boolean mask:

```
def first_minute(x):
    return x - x.min() < pd.Timedelta(1, unit='m')

df['isin_first_minute'] = (df.groupby('participant')['start_time']
                             .transform(first_minute))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      id  participant              start_time  isin_first_minute
0  44414         1556 2023-04-18 09:35:41.100               True
1  36905         1435 2023-04-18 09:35:41.300               True
2  44416         1556 2023-04-18 09:35:42.100               True
3  44417         1556 2023-04-18 09:35:42.900               True
4  44418         1222 2023-04-18 09:35:43.100               True
5  44356         1899 2023-04-18 23:01:29.400               True
```

**Update**

To extract only matching rows, you can use:

```
m = df.groupby('participant')['start_time'].transform(first_minute)
df_first_minute = df[m]
```

Comment: @London-35. Do you know how can you filter your dataframe with the boolean values? I updated my answer, can you check it please?